# ec2 instance outside the rdp. error: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rdp, inbound

ec2 instance running on windows server. When I am trying to access inside the rdp connection its working fine. But when I am trying to access it outside the rdp then its give me error: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

```
I have set the below inbound rules for security group. 

** HTTP TCP 80  0.0.0.0/0 **
** HTTP TCP 80  ::/0 **
** SSH  TCP 22  --.--.--.--/-- **
** RDP  TCP 3389 --.--.--.--/--**
```

**Note**: I have running ec2 instance running on windows server

Comment: Could you elaborate on "inside the RDP connection" and "outside the RDP connection"

Comment: Sure, _inside RDP connection means_ :     get the rdp extension files from aws console and double click on it. and enter the servername, username and password  and open the remote connection where in my case its working fine I accessed  aws public dns.

_outside rdp connection_ :   access aws public dns anywhere on anymachine.

Answer (score 0):

To determine if your EC2 security groups allow unrestricted RDP access, perform the following:

Using AWS Console
01 Sign in to the AWS Management Console.

02 Navigate to EC2 dashboard at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/.

03 In the left navigation panel, under NETWORK & SECURITY section, choose Security Groups.

04 Click inside the attributes filter box located under the dashboard top menu and select the following options from the dropdown list:

Choose Protocol and select TCP from the protocols list.
Choose Port Range then select RDP as filter input.

05 Select an EC2 security group returned as result.

06 Select the Inbound tab from the dashboard bottom panel.

07 Verify the value available in the Source column for any inbound/ingress rules with the Port Range set to 3389. If one or more rules have the source set to 0.0.0.0/0 or ::/0 (Anywhere), the selected security group allows unrestricted traffic on port 3389, therefore the RDP access to the associated EC2 instance(s) is not secured.

08 Repeat steps no. 5 – 7 to verify the rest of the EC2 security groups returned as result at step no. 4.

09 Change the AWS region from the navigation bar and repeat the audit process for other regions.

Comment: I have make change for same But I did not get any luck, Is there any wat to sort out this problem?

Comment: Do you already testing with Telnet to 3389 from outside? Is refused?

Comment: No But I  tested with ssh connection its give me  connection refused error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow port 3389 (for RDP) in your security group's inbound rules.

Eg.

```
+------+----------+------------+-----------+-------------+
| Type | Protocol | Port range |  Source   | Description |
----------------------------------------------------------
| RDP  | TCP      |       3389 | 0.0.0.0/0 | IP V4       |
| RDP  | TCP      |       3389 | ::/0      | IP V6       |
+------+----------+------------+-----------+-------------+
```

The above example opens the 3389 port for the world. Better restrict it to the IP address from where your are accessing the machine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer But I dont allow access public to  my rdp connection... Thats why I allow rdp connection to my  IP only. Even So I change the  rules as per  your suggestion but my bad luck till giving me same error!

Comment: @Vickysw: How are you connecting to the EC2 instance? Are you using Microsoft's RDP tool?

Comment: No, I dont used Microsoft`s RDP tool. I am using remmina for rdp connection.

Answer (score 0):

Ok! Guys here is your answer!

If your ec2 instance running on windows server and you want to your application available for publicly then follow below steps:

1. Open your windows server using  rdp files on your local machine.
2. Configure your windows firewall and  allow it for all Inbound Rules.

That`s it.. It will be very helpfull.